# Quelles seraient d’autres variantes de « se tourner vers »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, synonymes, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Faute de ressources financières, Robert s’est tourné vers le crime organisé.

> Faute de ressources financières, Robert est passé du côté du crime organisé.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Robert a basculé du côté du crime organisé.
> Robert s'est dirigé vers le crime organisé.
> Robert s'est reconverti dans le crime organisé.

Answer (score 2):

> Robert a choisi ...

> Robert s'est orienté ...

> Robert a dérivé vers ...

> Robert a glissé dans ...

Answer (score 0):

On ne peut pas considérer que « *passer du côté de* » soit un synonyme de « *se tourner vers* ». Le premier indique un processus révolu alors que le second dénote un processus en cours.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tourner))
> **II.** − Empl. pronom.
> **A.** −
> **3.** Au fig. Se diriger, s'acheminer vers quelque chose.
> ♦  L'Idéalisme, réalisé anthropomorphiquement par des Juifs, produisit le Christianisme. Alors tout l'Occident se tourna avec tant d'empressement vers l'idéal (...) que l'on crut pouvoir immédiatement, et sans l'intermédiaire de cette vie, se réunir à la Beauté divine (P. Leroux, Humanité, 1840, p. 92).
> ♦ Toutes les imaginations humaines, fraîches ou flétries, tristes ou joyeuses, se tournent vers le passé, curieuses d'y pénétrer (A. France, Vie fleur, 1922, p. 322).

La locution verbale  « chercher du côté de » a cependant un sens similaire.

- Faute de ressources financières, Robert *a cherché du côté du* crime organisé.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chercher))
> **I.** − [L'idée dominante est celle de tentative dont le résultat n'est pas acquis d'avance]
> **A.** − [L'idée implique un mouvement physique] Aller de-ci et de-là, se donner du mouvement et de la peine pour découvrir ou trouver quelqu'un ou quelque chose.

« *S'intéresser à* » est une autre possibilité qui exprime cette idée d'investigation d'une nouvelle voie, e tendance vers quelque chose d'autre.

- Faute de ressources financières, Robert *s'est intéressé au* crime organisé.

Comment: More than that, "se tourner vers le crime organisé" means more or less  that he asks help from organised crime, in th other hand, "est passé du côté du crime organisé" means that he became a part of criminal organisations ..

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington  Possibly so, but not necessarily, ; there is no cetitude that this implies a quest for support from individuals already well established in the world of organised crime, and it is just as well possible that this initiative spells plainly as being a choice for practices that are well known to be typical of those of organized crime, that is, in other words, that person might just be reverting to practices that he knows very well to be those of organised crime (blackmail, bribing of officials, hiring of hitmen, etc.), a typical attitude of rotten policemen, by the way.

Comment: yes it's true that there is no certitude ... what I tried to highlith is that, "se tourner vers [someone or something]" give to me the immediate feeling that the one who turns towards is not a part of what he is turning towards .. but the one who "est passé du côté de" is now a part of something he join ...